# Spring Security Authentication using single table in database

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

How can I integrate spring security using only one table which contains username,password and userRoles in tbl_users then what will be the query for it in

```
<authentication-manager>
        <authentication-provider>
            <jdbc-user-service data-source-ref="dataSource"
                users-by-username-query=""
                authorities-by-username-query="" />
        </authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>
```

Every Help will be appreciated.
Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: Implement custom `UserDetailsService`.

Answer (score 0):

```
<authentication-manager>
    <authentication-provider>
        <jdbc-user-service data-source-ref="dataSource"

       users-by-username-query="
         SELECT USERNAME, PASSWORD 
         FROM USER_TABLE
         WHERE USERNAME=?;"

       authorities-by-username-query="
        SELECT u.USERNAME, r.ROLENAME 
        FROM USER_TABLE u, USER_TABLE r
        WHERE u.ID = r.USERID
        AND u.USERNAME=?;"
        />
    </authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>
```